# Function needs access to variables in another function

Tags: c++, function, class, animation

Im trying to create a few function, one to setup an animation, the second to play it, i can set it up find but the second function needs to access the first in order to get some of the variables

```
    void fire::fireSetup(void)
{

    fireTexture.loadFromFile("firesprite.png");

    Animation fireSmall;
    fireSmall.setSpriteSheet(fireTexture);
    fireSmall.addFrame(sf::IntRect(64, 0, 64, 64));
    fireSmall.addFrame(sf::IntRect(128, 0, 64, 64));
    fireSmall.addFrame(sf::IntRect(192, 0, 64, 64));
    fireSmall.addFrame(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 64, 64));

    AnimatedSprite animatedSprite(sf::seconds(0.1), false, true);
    animatedSprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(300,300));

}

void fire::fireAnim(void)
{
    sf::Time frameTime = fireClock.restart();
    animatedSprite.play(fireSmall);
    animatedSprite.update(frameTime);
    window.mywindow.draw(animatedSprite);
}
```

as you can see the function `fireAnim` needs to know what `animatedSprite` and `fireSmall` is but i can't figure out how to do it.

if its any use my header class is the following

```
    class fire
{
private:


public:
    sf::Clock fireClock;
    sf::Texture fireTexture;


    void fireSetup(void);
    void fireAnim(void);

};
```

Comment: Where is animatedSprite supposed to come from? If it is owned by the caller of fireAnim() then pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: You could create a private class variable that is shared by both functions.

Comment: My goal is to set up the sprite, such as the frames and texture etc, then loop the animation, if i make it one function then my while loop will keep cycling through the sprites setup, which i would assume means keeps loading the same texture etc over and over. Sorry if this seems silly, im in the learning phase of c++

Comment: Data is typically shared across methods (functions) in a class by being members of that class. Ideally they would be private members of the class. Create them in the class's constructor, destroy them in the class's destructor.

Answer (score 3):

Could you make those variables members of the class rather than local to the function?

e.g. (changing the [type] to the right type of course):

```
class fire
{
    private: 
        [type] anmatedsprite;
        [type] firesmall;



    public:
        sf::Clock fireClock;
        sf::Texture fireTexture;


    void fireSetup(void);
    void fireAnim(void);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Google about encapsulation principles in C++, when you understand the meaning of private, protected and pubic, then Google for class **friendship**. In short, friendship allows one class' members to "see" the friendly class' private members. I hope this helps.